# How to create a reusable UI component

Tags: android

This seems like a simple question that I should be able to find easily but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to create a reusable UI component for Android. Specifically I'm trying to create this snippet that I use EVERYWHERE into a reusable component to make the code smaller.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">          
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
        android:id="@+id/my_text_id"
        android:text="My field"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
        android:text="My value"
        android:id="@+id/my_value_id"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

These are used like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/background_normal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:paddingBottom="0dp"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingRight="10dp"
             android:paddingTop="10dp">         
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:id="@+id/my_text_id"
                android:text="My field"/>

             <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:text="My value"
                android:id="@+id/my_value_id"/>

          </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:paddingBottom="0dp"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingRight="10dp"
             android:paddingTop="10dp">         
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:id="@+id/my_text_id2"
                android:text="My field2"/>

             <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:text="My value2"
                android:id="@+id/my_value_id2"/>

          </RelativeLayout>
          .... etc ....
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm hoping to be able to access both text boxes to assign values inside that will be added with the `<include />` tag to a layout. Does anyone know how to do this?

I've seen http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html but I don't seem to see how to assign multiple of the same field.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update** These are used to put a TextView on the left of the screen and another on the right that are lined up together. Not sure how to describe it, but these are used in a ScrollView.

Comment: where you want to re-use this layout exactly? for titlebar or else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<include />` include tag as stated in **[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)**

To find the component inside your layout:

```
findViewById(R.id.includedComponent)
```

where `R.id.includedComponent` is a name of the included component.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I suppose my question should have been asking how to reference the inner views, but you figured that out.

Comment: link not valid anymore: 404 not found

Comment: @netimen i will try to update  latest once. as dev. site is changed need to find correct link..

Comment: Another link which helps -http://docs.huihoo.com/android/2.1/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html

Comment: I think this is the new link - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 2):

Use "include" and "merge" to "inject" layouts into an existing layout. Once you include, you can reference the views much as you would if they were already in the layout.

If you want to "include" the same layout multiple times, then you have two choices:

a) Use a ListView and an adapter to repeat the view 
b) Inflate the views in code and add them manually by using addView(). As you inflate each view, you can use findViewById to target widgets specifically in that view.